# How to find IEnumerable<dynamic> element type?

Tags: c#, .net

If I try

```
List<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic> { "blah" };
var type = list.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

I get 'object' instead of `string`. How to get "real" type?

Comment: 98 times out of 100 dynamic isnt the right approach and causes more problems then its solves. i say this because if you could remove the dynamic part of what you are doing you would find subsequent code solutions will be much more satisfying, less hacky and more predictable

Comment: What if your list contains different types? e.g. `List<dynamic> { "blah", 1 }`? As TheGeneral already said, you usually don´t need `dynamic` at all in order to get something "dynamic".

Comment: @TheGeneral I agree with you, but dynamic comes from generated code and not controlled by me.

Comment: @HimBromBeere good point, didn't thought about this problem.

Comment: @PeterDuniho the duplicate question is different question. Event so the answer has useful information it is not possible to find it asking **my** question.

Comment: The question isn't whether searching on your literal question would find the duplicate. The question is whether the duplicate is in fact asking about the same issue, and has the same answer. Which it is and does. You will need to develop the skill of generalization and using that to execute a variety of different searches that each have keywords relevant to but not literally verbatim of your question, so that you can find such answers.

Comment: @PeterDuniho still not agree with you. "How to know is it dynamic" is not generalization of "How to know what is dynamic behind". I suspect that you knew it is not possible that's why you asked the "right" question and got this answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try accessing the value first and then determine the type.**

```
List<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic> { "blah", 15 };
var type = list[0].GetType();
Console.WriteLine(type); // prints out System.String

type = list[1].GetType();
Console.WriteLine(type); // prints out System.Int32
```

And if you want a list of all types, use Linq:

```
var types = list.Select(item => item.GetType());

// print out
foreach (var t in types) {
    Console.WriteLine(t);
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer to not access the items but it seems the only possible solution because of different types behind the `dynamic` as mentioned by @HimBromBeere.

Answer (score 0):

`Object` IS the real type here. You can think of `dynamic` in C# as an object with special behavior, where member binding happens at runtime rather than compile time. For most types this works like a shortcut to reflection.